# Dynamically generating directive name in Vue Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js

I'm using a dropdown from Vue bootstrap, and I want to include collapsable elements within it. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a button that opens and closes each element within the collapsable list.

The way Vue bootstrap does this is by giving the collapsable element an id that matches up to the directive name of the button.

My issue is that when generating a number of items with `v-for`, I am not able to dynamically generate directive names (I am able to generate id names however). See my code below:

```
            <b-dropdown-item-button disabled v-for="(superPortfolio, index) in portfolio.hierarchy">{{superPortfolio.superPortfolioName}}<b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse' + 0" variant="primary"></b-btn>
              <b-collapse v-bind:id="'collapse' + index" class="mt-2">
                <b-card>

                </b-card>
              </b-collapse>
            </b-dropdown-item-button>

        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

I would like to be able to give the dropdown item a directive like `v-b-toggle="'collapse' + {{index}}"` rather than hardcoding it like I've done above (`v-b-toggle="'collapse' + 0"`)

Comment: `v-b-toggle="'collapse' + index"`

Comment: Check the updated answer if you still care a bit hehe

Answer (score 10):

You need to simply bind on that directive as well.

```
<b-btn v-bind:v-b-toggle="'collapse' + index" variant="primary"></b-btn>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

EDIT: v-b-toggle does not need bind `:` so use like

```
<b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse' + index" variant="primary"></b-btn>
```

Comment: This seems like it should do the trick, and my components are rendering with the directive of "collapse0" etc. However, that is still not working for some reason - I feel like it might have to do with vue-bootstrap - when the component is rendered it converts the directive name to `aria-controls0`, and doesn't do that when I bind to the directive...