# How to add/edit vue-bootstrap tag dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to create components with individual IDs. Where I used vue-bootstrap for minimize button. In `<i class="material-icons m-1" v-b-toggle.collapse-componentID> minimize </i>` componentID should be changed according to given number. If componentID is "1" it should render as "v-b-toggle.collapse-1" and id="collapse-componentID" as id="collapse-1".

I tried use class bind dynamically. since "v-b-toggle.collapse-componentID" is not a class its not working. can any one help me with this?

```
<div>
  <b-jumbotron class="canvaArea">
    <div class="btn-min-close">
      <i class="material-icons m-1" v-b-toggle.collapse-componentID> minimize </i>
      <i class="material-icons" @click="deleteAllElement"> close </i>
    </div>
  <!-- v-b-toggle.collapse-componentID -->
    <b-collapse visible id="collapse-componentID">
      <formContainer/>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-jumbotron>
  <i @click="addComponent" class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389883/dynamically-generating-directive-name-in-vue-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `id` attributes you can simply use template literals :

```
 <b-collapse visible :id=`collapse-${componentID}`>
```

For the other attributes bootstrap components you might have to create a custom directive :

```js
var componentsLength = 4;
for (let i = 1; i <= componentsLength; i++) {
  Vue.directive(`b-toggle-collapse-${i}`, {
    inserted: function(el) {
      // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
      // add styles here ...i will change bg color for instance
      var colors = ['red', 'skyblue', 'orange', 'white'];
      el.style.backgroundColor = colors[i - 1]
    }
  })
}

new Vue({el:"#app"})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-b-toggle-collapse-1>button1</button>
  <button v-b-toggle-collapse-2>button2</button>
  <button v-b-toggle-collapse-3>button3</button>
  <button v-b-toggle-collapse-4>button4</button>
</div>
```

Read more about custom directives : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: My problem is exactly similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389883/dynamically-generating-directive-name-in-vue-bootstrap?answertab=oldest#tab-top